# How can 4 hours of votes suddenly appear?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

After checking in on regular intervals (being about every twenty minutes or so ), I just got this about 10 minutes ago:

[image]

How is this possible when I know that all of those down-votes did not exist 20 minutes ago and are yet reported as 3 to 4 hours ago?  It appears that the reputation page failed to update for about 4 hours, is there some sort of a bug here?

Answer (score 18):

> how is this possible that this is not some damn fool with a vendetta doing this?

Nothing new here, in terms of how other users behave.

That's why we have a fraud detection script that runs days and reverses such votes.

If these don't get reversed within 48 hours, **then** you should raise an issue.

---

> How is this possible when I know that all of those down-votes did not exist 20 minutes ago and are yet reported as 3 to 4 hours ago?

We don't show realtime alerts for negative reputation - this is a well known and well established convention here on Stack Exchange that's been around for years.

You only got notified once that upvote came in that there were reputation changes.

The user page is cached; so updates that the vote fraud detection takes into account may not be immediately apparent on your profile. [Eventual consistency](http://dbareactions.com/post/98987241406/after-we-explain-eventual-consistency-to-our), and all that.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I'm purging the comments because they went way off-topic here.

Comment: @NeilLunn You can express any opinion you want about Stack Overflow, so long as you back it up with research, facts, and post it as a meta question where you're inviting discussion.  Otherwise, it's off topic.  It's most especially off topic in the comments of an unrelated answer.